# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in [indexPath row]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am customizing my table cells. I have this code (simplified) which is giving me an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when trying to access `[indexPath row]`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WCFPictureCell";
    static NSString *CellNib = @"WCFPictureCell";
    WCFPictureCell *cell = (WCFPictureCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (WCFPictureCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSLog(@"iph    %@", indexPath);
    NSLog(@"iphrow %@", [indexPath row]);
    return cell;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `row` method of `NSIndexPath` returns a `NSInteger`.
That's a primitive type, not an object.

So you can't print it using `%@`.

What you want is:

```
NSLog( @"iphrow %i", [ indexPath row ] );
```

You are getting a segmentation fault because `%@` is used for a pointer to an object.
As you are passing an integer, NSLog will try to print an object at the memory address specified by the integer value.

Comment: What was your reason for using `%i`? I have always used `%d` for an integer and I am aware `NSInteger` is just a typedef of `int` but is there a reason for using it other than preference?

Comment: `%i` and `%d` are the same thing with `printf`. Both are used for signed integers. It's just a question of habit. But note `%i` and `%d` have a different meaning in `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code (Refactor a bit). Your error is on  [indexPath row] which return int use (%i not %@)

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    WCFPictureCell *cell = (WCFPictureCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"WCFPictureCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WCFPictureCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
NSLog(@"iph    %@", indexPath);
NSLog(@"iphrow %i", [indexPath row]);
return cell; }
```